# Audio background mode not working with react-native-track-player

Tags: ios, react-native, audio, background, react-native-track-player

I'm currently use `react-native-track-player` version `1.1.8` to stream audio from Internet.
It works fine (`react-native` version `0.61.4`)

I would like now to use it in background mode, to be able to continue to listen to radio if my app is in background mode.

I followed instructions from https://react-native-kit.github.io/react-native-track-player/background/, so add capabilities in xCode, which should be enough.

It doesn't work so I also add

```
TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
    stopWithApp: false
});
```

but stil not working on real device on iOS 13.
I can see this message when the app goes background :

```
Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1),
or it may have already been ended. 
Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
```

But breakpoint does not give additional informations.

Any idea or experience with this audio library in background mode?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of `react-native-track-player` are you using? I got background mode working with version `1.1.8` following the instructions you linked

Comment: @Ballenato I updated the question with version number and additional informations

Comment: the message "can't end backgroundtask..." is a iOS 13 bug

Comment: @Ilario Ok I saw that apparently it's an iOS bug. Anyway it's a warning and I don't think it's the cause of the problem but the consequence, my background audio is stopped for whatever reason, and then this message appears.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the background permissions structure in iOS 13 changed.

I had the same issue and solved it by:

1. Ticking **Background processing** as well in Background modes:
   [image]
2. Adding **Permitted background task scheduler identifiers** to my app target at Xcode (info tab) with my app identifier as value.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Anyway it does not work for me. When you say app identifier, can you confirm it's the same as $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) ?

Comment: Another thing : the problem appears only on the physical device, not on the simulator.

Comment: I can confirm that playing audio while the app is in background requires activating _Background processing_, so the [Track Player docs](https://react-native-track-player.js.org/background) should be updated. I don't see _Permitted background task scheduler identifiers_ anywhere in the _Info_ tab - but then, the _Custom iOS Target Properties_ table in current Xcode _Version 12.1 (12A7403)_ is completely useless, the columns can't be expanded, so its values are hardly visible.

Answer (score 2):

1.Ticking Background processing as well in Background modes:

[Background modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zstAF.png)

2.Adding Permitted background task scheduler identifiers to my app target at Xcode (info tab) with my app identifier as value.

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, ticking, in Xcode,  `Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture` was the thing that did the trick. I didn't need to tick `Background Processing`

[image]